# Child process steals focus. How to get it back without bothering user?

Tags: c++, winapi

I created child process from console application

```
CreateProcess(NULL, command, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &in, &out);
```

Where

- `command` is the command line for the application I run `pvw32 img.jpg` ([pictView](http://www.pictview.com/) to show some image).
- `in` is a STARTUPINFO struct (I tried STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW flag but tough luck, pictView steals focus by some of it's processess)

I tried to give the pictView some time and then kindly take the focus back

```
Sleep(1000);
SwitchToThisWindow(hwnd,TRUE);
```

I got the focus (the cursor is blinking again in my console), but the icon in the task bar flashes several times and the input is not allowed until I hit Alt+Tab.

I also tried to set the z-order, to launch the pictView minimized, even to suspend it, but he just doesn't want to give up easily. The only way how to get the focus back is to kill the pictView.

**Is there any way how to get the focus back without bothering the user with Alt+Tab?**

Note: there was no focus-stealing problem with [simpView](http://userfo.deviantart.com/art/Simpview-0-6-1-Image-viewer-168046483), but I'd like to stay with pictView for performance reasons.

Comment: You could try setting STARTUPINFO.wShowWindow to SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE.  This is however only a hint to a process, it doesn't have to use it.

Comment: In addition to using the `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` flag, did you also set the `wShowWindow` value of the `STARTUPINFO` structure to something like `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE` or `SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVATE`?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, however the pictView just ignores it. I am wondering if there could be a way to launch the pictView in some kind of sandbox that teaches its processess good manners?

Comment: The fact that your taskbar button flashes means your app is NOT ALLOWED to put its window back into the foreground automatically.  The documentation for [`SetForegroundWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx) outlines the requirements for setting a foreground to the foreground. Once your app starts pictView and it pops into the foreground, your app no longer qualifies to take back the foreground without user intervention (ie, click on the flashing taskbar button or Alt+Tab to your window).

Comment: I don't know if you're aware of this, but all applications, even console applications, can create windows. Especially given that you're already concerned about performance, there is a possible simpler approach: don't launch a new process in the first place, create your own viewer.

Comment: @hvd actually I created a window from the console. Which of course has its own process. I prefered to use 3rd party app rather to create viewer on my own. The problem was that its processes had been stealing the focus, which I solved thanks to Remy's suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Remy Lebeau points out, [SetForegroundWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx) outlines the requirements for setting a foreground to the foreground. pictView played dirty, so I [used dirty tricks too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633532.aspx):

```
LockSetForegroundWindow(LSFW_LOCK);
```

executed from the console application prevented pictView to steal its focus. Everything run smoothly now.